# Deadlock instead of an exception when calling get() from the inside FutureTask.run()

Tags: java.util.concurrent, java-threads

Recently, due to an error in my code, I created a recursive call (infinite loop, in fact). One of the methods involved in the loop used a pre-computed task. It can be summarized as:

```java
ConcurrentHashMap<String, FutureTask<Integer>> cache = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

int method1() {
  var task = cache.computeIfAbsent("key", k -> new FutureTask<>(this::method2));
  task.run();
  try {
    return task.get();
  } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
  }
}

int method2() {
  if (1 + 1 != 4) { // this wasn't so obvious of course...
    return method1();
  }
  return 1;
}
```

In short: `FutureTask`'s `get()` was called while inside its `run()` execution.

To my surprise, it resulted in a deadlock, as `get()` makes no checks and parks the current thread unconditionally.

I know I shot myself in the foot with low-level primitives, but is there a reason or use case why `get()` doesn't make a check and
throw an exception when called from the same thread as the runner thread of the task?